# Не работает функция appendTo() на JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытался написать форму комментариев, но не работает функция appendTo()

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", "#send", function() {
    var comment = $("textarea").val();
    $("<p>" + comment + "</p>").appendTo("#comment");
  });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: auto;
  width: 342px;
}

.wrapper #send {
  background: #ccc;
  border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
  border: 1px solid #9d9d9d;
  padding: 6px;
}

.wrapper textarea {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="comment"></div>

  <form method="post" name="form">
    <textarea cols="45" rows="10" placeholder="Напишите коментарий..."></textarea><br /><br />
    <center><input id="send" name="send" type="submit" value="Отправить"></center>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Надо предотвращать дефолтное действие кнопки `submit`. Например через  **[preventDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault)**;

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(document).on("click", "#send", function (event) {
          event.preventDefault(); // <!---- ВАЖНО!!!
          var comment = $("textarea").val();
          $("<p>" + comment + "</p>").appendTo("#comment");
        });
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
        background:#eee;
        padding:10px;
        margin:auto;
        width:342px;
      }

.wrapper #send {
        background: #ccc;
        border-radius: 5px;
        outline: none;
        border:1px solid #9d9d9d;
        padding:6px;
      }

.wrapper textarea {
        outline: none;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class = "wrapper">
      <div id = "comment"></div>

      <form method = "post" name = "form">
        <textarea cols = "45" rows = "10" placeholder="Напишите коментарий...">         </textarea><br /><br />
        <center><input id = "send" name = "send" type = "submit" value =                 "Отправить"></center>
      </form>
</div>
```